# Submitting value that is different to item label, Google Forms (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, response, google-forms

I am fairly new to Google Script and I have come across an issue.
I would like to submit a different value to the label of the multiple choice option selected.

I am writing a script that generates a form to signup for any one of the events happening with in the next two weeks. These events are pulled from a calendar. For disambiguation reasons I am adding the event date to the event name before adding the array to the MulipleChoice item list.

I want to submit the Event ID rather than the newly created name as it will make the script's management of the responses so much simpler.

Hence This is what the multiple choice list would look like:

```
[] Event 1 20/06/14
[] Event 2 22/06/14
[] Event 3 23/06/14
[] Event 4 27/06/14
[] Event 5 29/06/14
```

Then If the user selects Event 2, I would like the value submitted to the responses spreadsheet to be Event 2's ID rather than "Event 2 22/06/14".

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an easier way:

Create a sheet where you store Events name and corresponding ID.

Then add a column in your answer sheet which will get the ID corresponding to the event name using either a script or ARRAYFORMULA + Vlookup

Hope this help,